# On starting AWS SSM Agent, it is throwing 'AuthorizationFailureException'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

Below are the steps that I performed for setup :

- Created a new windows server 2012 EC2 instance and then connected
  with it using the remote desktop connection.
- Installed EC2 config service which automatically installs
  AmazonSSMAgent service.
- Both EC2 and SSM services are running and in error logs, it is throwing some 'no chain provider exception' which is fine because I have not provided aws credentials yet.
- Created a new IAM user and give him administrative policy access and
  created three environment variables providing access_key,
  secret_access_key and region_id.
- Then I restarted AmazonSSMAgent service, then the exception changed to below exception:

  ```
   status code: 400, request id: 400b4c75-eae2-11e7-a120-d33083d55d1f 2017-12-27 08:45:13 ERROR [HandleAwsError @ awserr.go.48] [instanceID=i-084646fb32d8a7b6d] [MessagingDeliveryService] error when calling AWS APIs. error details - GetMessages Error: AuthorizationFailureException:
  ```

Please suggest what i am doing wrong or any steps that i have missed or any other way to do this.

Comment: The EC2 instance needs AmazonEC2RoleforSSM permission. To give that permission to an EC2 instance, launch the instance with an appropriate IAM role. You shouldn't try to do this IAM users (that's for people, not machines).

Comment: Hi, I have already attached a role with 'AmazonEC2RoleforSSM' policy to the instance. My ultimate goal is to use cloudwatchPlugin to monitor logs. I have put the Cloudwatch json file in plugin location. But it didn't work and there was this exception in logs. So I think this exception is the reason logs are not getting stored into Cloudwatch service.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest SSM Agent (older Windows AMIs use EC2Config Service instead of the SSM Agent). And verify steps required here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-ssm-win.html

Comment: The [AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/setup-instance-profile.html) Policy is a bit more restrictive.